# Do I need to specify a background-color if using a linear-gradient?

Tags: css, html

I have more code that I am wondering if could be simplified.

```
background-color: #5bb75b;
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #62c462, #51a351);
```

Can someone confirm is the first line needed if I am only using a very new browser.

Comment: Your background-color is useful if you are on an old browser that does not interpret line-gradient. For example, line-gradient is supported on IE10+, os background-color is useful for IE9 and less.

Comment: It's not about what browser ***you*** are using...it's about the browser the ***viewer*** is using.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will only need to use the background color if you intend for this site to be seen on older browsers that does not support gradients.

Comment: `older browsers` which browsers? Please be more specific.

Comment: IE 8 or below I believe.